# Hardhat HH801 error while installing

Tags: hardhat

I am having hardhat HH801 error while working on hardhat , i installed hardhat version 2.12.2 and"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^2.0.0

Comment: Can you post your package.json file here?